# Is there a constexpr which lets me determine if there is an output operator (<<) for a particular type?

Tags: c++, if-constexpr

In order to prevent the compiler to apply e.g. a `std::vector<T>` to a statement like `std::cout << u`, I would like to do something like this:

```
if constexpr (std::has_output_operator<U>) {
    std::cout << u;
}
```

Is there some way to achieve this?

**EDIT** (clarification)
I am working on printf-like function which can also print strings and vectors of POD and strings (and vectors thereof).

I would like to extend this functionality to any type which has an output operator.

The actual formatting for non-vector types is done by the functions `simpleFormat()`:

```
// simpleFormat
//  special case for single string
//
std::string simpleFormat(const std::string sFormat, const std::string t) {
    size_t required = snprintf(NULL, 0, sFormat.c_str(), t.c_str());
    char sTemp[required+1];
    sprintf(sTemp, sFormat.c_str(), t.c_str());
    return std::string(sTemp);
} 

// simpleFormat
//  catch for vectors (should not be sent to simpleFormat)
template<typename T>
std::string simpleFormat(const std::string sFormat, const std::vector<T> t) {
    return "";
}

// simpleFormat
//  formatting PODs and Objects with output operator a char using     
template<typename T>
std::string simpleFormat(const std::string sFormat, const T t) {
    std::string sRes = "";

    if (sFormat.size() > 0) {
        if (sFormat != "%O") {
            size_t required = snprintf(NULL, 0, sFormat.c_str(), t);
            char sTemp[required+1];
            sprintf(sTemp, sFormat.c_str(), t);
            sRes = std::string(sTemp);
        } else {
            std::stringstream ss("");
            ss << t;
            sRes += ss.str();    
        }
    } 

   return sRes;
}
```

When i compile this for some applications, get the error

```
In file included from AgentCounter.cpp:6: 
../utils/stdstrutilsT.h: In instantiation of ‘std::string simpleFormat(std::string, T) [with T = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’: 
../utils/stdstrutilsT.h:195:33:   required from ‘std::string recursiveFormat(stringvec&, stringvec&, uint, T, Args ...) [with T = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; Args = {long long unsigned int}; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; stringvec = std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; uint = unsigned int]’ 
../utils/stdstrutilsT.h:281:31:   required from ‘std::string stdsprintf(std::string, Args ...) [with Args = {__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, long long unsigned int}; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’ 
../utils/stdstrutilsT.h:291:34:   required from ‘void stdprintf(std::string, Args ...) [with Args = {__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, long long unsigned int}; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’ 
AgentCounter.cpp:326:22:   required from here 
../utils/stdstrutilsT.h:165:28: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::stringstream’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>’} and ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >’) 
 165 |                         ss << t; 
     |                         ~~~^~~~
```

Even though i have a `simpleFormat()` variant for vectors, the compiler still wants to fit the `std::vector` into the POD variant.

That is why i hope there is `constexpr` which lets me find out if the passed type has an output operator.

Of course if there are other possibilities to stop the compiler from applying vectors to my non-vector function, i'd like to learn about them.

Comment: You could define a concept. Or some other SFINAE voodoo.

Comment: Are you restricted to an earlier C++ standard?  I notice a very large edit after getting a good C++20 answer.  Is that answer unacceptable?  If so, can you clarify why?

Comment: No, Brian Bi's answer is good and i accepted it. His answer arrived while i was editing my original post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done straightforwardly using the C++20 *requires-expression*, which checks whether its operand is valid:

```
if constexpr (requires { std::cout << u; })
```

You can also define a named [concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) with the *requires-expression* and then use it in place of the *requires-expression* every time you need it.